# jwplayer doesn't work on ie8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, jwplayer

Jwplayer doesn't work for me on Internet explorer 8.
It works on all borwsers only ie8.
Here is my code

```
<div class="player_zone">
 <div id="video_0"></div>
 <script>
 jwplayer_setup("video_0","/multimedias/THX1138.mp4","/multimedias/THXDuvall.jpg");</script>
 </div>
<script> 
function jwplayer_setup(id,path,img){//
 jwplayer(id).setup({//
  file: path,
  image: img,
  width: 'auto',
  height:'100%',
  advertising: {
   client: 'bla',
   tag: 'bla bla'
 }
});
```

Comment: Please provide a link.

Comment: what is the error, it is showing

Answer (score 2):

Of course, everything works fine except in IE, try to upgrade to IE11